# CSS allow background image to stretch but not shrink

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure why I cant find this, I want to allow certain div backgrounds to stretch horizontally but not to shrink (Or better yet, set a point it is allowed to shrink horizontally but not unlimited). I feel like this should be an easy answer, something to do with min-width and max-width maybe? I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So once they expand you dont want them to shrink again?

Comment: Please add a code example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @asdf No, I want them to stretch for displays such as a 1080p display, but when on mobile I don't want them shrinking, I would rather them fill at 100% the original image size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there you go, use `background-size:cover`:

this is a div sized 450X480, and a background sized 400X400

```css
div{
  width:450px;
  height:480px;
  background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, my Google-fu is weak today. I knew it was  a simple answer, thanks!